# What is the point of using a Composite hash range partition

Tags: sql, oracle, database-partitioning

If I have a table that has values in ranges, then I should create a range partition... if the table does not have data that can fit in a range or list portion, then a hash partition should be created. Then what is the point of joining multiple partitions together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-52D62B9A-13CB-40EE-AFA2-6140CC3BEC06.htm) cover this.

**When to Use Composite Range-Hash Partitioning**

> Composite range-hash partitioning is particularly common for tables
>   that store history, are very large consequently, and are frequently
>   joined with other large tables. For these types of tables (typical of
>   data warehouse systems), composite range-hash partitioning provides
>   the benefit of partition pruning at the range level with the
>   opportunity to perform parallel full or partial partition-wise joins
>   at the hash level. Specific cases can benefit from partition pruning
>   on both dimensions for specific SQL statements.
>
> Composite range-hash partitioning can also be used for tables that
>   traditionally use hash partitioning, but also use a rolling window
>   approach. Over time, data can be moved from one storage tier to
>   another storage tier, compressed, stored in a read-only tablespace,
>   and eventually purged. Information Lifecycle Management (ILM)
>   scenarios often use range partitions to implement a tiered storage
>   approach. See Managing and Maintaining Time-Based Information for more
>   details.
>
> Example 3-8 is an example of a range hash partitioned page_history
>   table of an Internet service provider. The table definition is
>   optimized for historical analysis for either specific client_ip values
>   (in which case queries benefit from partition pruning) or for analysis
>   across many IP addresses, in which case queries can take advantage of
>   full or partial partition-wise joins...